# What would they mean by this question?

Tags: digital-logic

[image: screenshot]

First let me say ignore the step e and step f, it's a typo.

Basically the Boolean expression is: (A./B) + (B.C)

Now it says convert it into NAND AND NOR function forms separately, which is confusing as hell because I don't know if the output is supposed to be the same, if they want 2 completely separate circuits one with a nand gate and one with a nor gate or what.

Now the next question says to construct the new circuits separately but then it says confirm ITS operation in accordance with THE truth table. I have the truth table and circuit for the first expression. Do I have ADD or is this question extremely vague?

Answer (score 1):

> Now it says convert it into NAND AND NOR function forms separately, which is confusing as hell because I don't know if the output is supposed to be the same, if they want 2 completely separate circuits one with a nand gate and one with a nor gate or what.

They want two distinct expressions, one with operations in the form of \$\overline {X \cdot Y}\$ and one with operations in the form of \$\overline {X + Y}\$.

> Now the next question says to construct the new circuits separately but then it says confirm ITS operation in accordance with THE truth table. I have the truth table and circuit for the first expression. Do I have ADD or is this question extremely vague?

The question is a little broken. It should read "their operation" in order to agree with the previous fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Any logic circuit can be made up of only NAND gates or only NOR gates. You are being asked to convert the initial Boolean equation into both forms (NAND/NOR) and explain any transformations used (such as De Morgan's Laws).

I believe the second part is to convert the equations into circuits using NAND and NOR gates, and then simulate them using Multisim.  Then show they are the same by showing the truth table dervied from the simulation are the same.